# Is it OK to post answers that offer terms used outside of their usual context by specific groups

Tags: discussion

Is it OK to post answers that offer terms used  outside of their usual context by specific groups?

Sorry to ask, but it seems that I may have stumbled on [my first post here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/182184/82990) and I thought I should check.

Well... Three downvotes in an hour I guess that answers the question. I'll delete the post and leave the link for 10k users.

Comment: I think the reason that answer was downvoted is because that wasn't a completely accurate use of the Evangelical "lukewarm".

Answer (score 2):

Ther's nothing wrong with suggesting a term that's only used by a specific group (or *jargon* as it's called), so long as it's properly identified as such.  You do, however, have to distinguish defining characteristics from accompanying  ones.  The sort of person the OP is asking about in the linked question might be called "worldly" and it's often a good description of them. But that, as well as your "lukewarm", is a description of the person not the behaviour, so it's not a good answer on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's OK, as long as it is an attempt to answer the OP.

It may also be judged (and voted on) by appropriateness; Your answer may work in that subgroup, but that's just not what the OP wanted.